# What's the notation of a set with multiple indices?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I want to take the maximum value of a set of values with three different indices:

$Y = \max (X_{1,1,1}, ..., X_{k,j,i})$

where: $i \in \{1,...,n\}$, $j \in \{1,...,m\}$, $k \in \{1,...,o\}$.

What would be the right notation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Y = \max_{i, j, k}(X_{1,1,1}, \dots)$$ is unambiguous as long as you've defined the ranges of $i, j, k$. If you really want to be on the safe side you could put $1 \leq i \leq n$, $1 \leq j \leq m$, $1 \leq k \leq o$ below the $\max$.

Comment: If you want to write out the full constraints, you might consider using `\substack`: $$\max_{\substack{1\leq i \leq n \\ 1\leq j\leq m\\1\leq k \leq o}}X_{i, j, k}$$(Right-click and "Show math as" -> "TeX Commands" to see how I used it). Although it gets ridiculously tall, the alternative is very long and not really that readable: $$\max_{1\leq i \leq n, 1\leq j\leq m, 1\leq k \leq o}X_{i, j, k}$$Really, it's better to write the constraints separately.

Comment: Thanks! That helped.
And what about: $\forall i\in I$, instead of $1\leq i \leq n$?

Comment: That would be just fine too.